# Comparing Documentum Docbases

Tags: content-management-system, documentum, documentum6.5, dfc

I would like to know is there a way to compare two doc bases of Documentum to ensure that they are same. For example, to compare the child-parent relationship for an object in 2 doc bases.

Any pointers towards this is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a query that gets all of the documents and folders (using a join), and order/compare the folder paths.  That would at least give you a way to determine if all the documents and folder exist.

However, unless you actually did a backup and load from database/content store to the other, the objects will all have different `r_object_id` values because it is based on the unique repository id.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. We are in the process of using the query to fetch and compare values. But wanted to know if there any inbuilt mechanism to do this from Documentum itself.

Comment: There is no direct comparison tool that I am aware of, and I have been using Documentum since version 5.2.5.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the inputs unicron. Much Appreciated. Will take the direction using DQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can start running the `Documentum job "dm_StateOfDocbase"` and compare the results.

If you need more specific informations about a relation, you can query the object `dm_relation_type`.